# How to refresh material-table grid from another component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, material-table

I have a Home component with a Grid component inside. The grid component has a MaterialTable component, which reads data from a remote server. This is the data parameter:

```
data={query =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    props.refreshGrid(query.page, query.pageSize, resolve, reject);
  })
}
```

and the action creator:

```
export function refreshGrid(page, pageSize, resolve, reject) {
  return async (dispatch, getState, api) => {

    api.taskhours.home(page, pageSize).then((response) => {
      var rows = response.data.rows;
      var total = response.data.total;

      // Grid data inside Redux Store is not being used right now, everything is done inside "resolve"
      dispatch(updateGrid(rows, page, pageSize, total)); 

      resolve({
        data: rows,
        page: page,
        totalCount: total,
        })
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error:",error);
    });

  };
}
```

All my components are functional (not using classes).

This works fine. However, I have a modal form in a different component, and when the user submits, I need to refresh the grid. Since I'm fetching the data from a remote server, material-table handles the row display, paging and loading, and the only way I know I can refresh the grid is by doing "tableRef.current.onQueryChange()". How can I trigger this from another component (the modal)?

I tried storing the ref inside the React Redux store, but that gave me a "Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component" error, while also making an infinite recursive function execution.

Also, since the grid updates itself, I need it to NOT re-render, otherwise I lose its internal state (page number, page size). I had to use React.memo() to avoid re-renders caused by the parent component, which looks very unclean. I'm pretty new with React so I may not be doing things right. Is there a better way to implement this?

**EDIT**

I managed to solve this using a different approach. Material-Table seems to be quite limited and not very redux-friendly. I based the solution on this post, thanks to *lfernando-silva* for the workaround:

https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/630

So basically I replaced the promise on "data" with a redux store variable. Since this method is only used to provide the entire data set (instead of a single page), you can't change the page and max amount of rows by default, so I had to manually set the "TablePagination" component attributes to display the correct values.

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <MaterialTable        
        title="title"
        tableRef={tableRef}
        columns={[
          // (...)
        ]}
        options={{
          emptyRowsWhenPaging: false
        }}
        data={
          props.grid.rows
        }
        onChangeRowsPerPage={pageSize => {
          refreshGrid(props.grid.page, pageSize);
        }}
        components={{
          Pagination: (componentProps) => <TablePagination
            {...componentProps}
            count={props.grid.total}
            page={props.grid.page}
            rowsPerPage={props.grid.pageSize}
            onChangePage={(evt, page) => {
                refreshGrid(page, props.grid.pageSize)
            }}
          />
        }}
        isLoading={props.grid.isLoading}
        actions={[
          // (...)
        ]}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

And my "refreshGrid" action creator:

```js
export function refreshGrid(page, pageSize) {
    return async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
        dispatch(startLoadingGrid());

        api.taskhours.home(page, pageSize).then((response) => {
            var rows = response.data.rows;
            var total = response.data.total;

            dispatch(updateGrid(rows, page, pageSize, total));
            dispatch(stopLoadingGrid());
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error:",error);
            dispatch(stopLoadingGrid());
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Why do you fetch the data in the table directly? There is your problem, I assume this from what code you gave. Share more code in order to proper help you. But for sure the data with the Promise inside the table is not ok

Comment: @Sabbin I could leave the fetch inside the "data" function (the grid), and then do the dispatch, but that's not my current problem. What I'm trying to do is to force a grid refresh from outside the component where the grid is rendered. I need either a way to access the tableRef, or to implement material-table in a better way, without using a fetch function in "data".

Comment: If you fetch your data in the grid component via `useSelector` or `mapStateToProps` either way when the data is changed the components will automatically rerender, so you will not need to force the refresh, it will be done automatically. If you could try and make a codesanbox with your issue, I could try to help you figure this out.

Comment: @Sabbin I think I get what you mean. There's a problem tho. The "data" promise is executed on render and also when the page changes. I could make the promise read data directly from the props (and make the refreshGrid somewhere else), but then when the page changes, I would need to execute the refreshGrid manually, otherwise the table data will never change.

Comment: I managed to solve it using a different approach. I'll update the post.